# How to fix The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, picturebox

I wrote a small code to make a slideshow program on a different screen. Everything is running fine also the delete and copy part, unless I do it right after the first picture is shown. If I do it later the debugger steps in.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\reflexscherm\root\Logo-teams2", "*.*");
    counter++;
    var maxcount = images.Count();
    textBox1.Text = maxcount.ToString();

    if (counter > maxcount - 1)
    {
        counter = 0;
        maxcount = images.Count();
    }

    //pb1.Image.Dispose();

    pb1.Image = Image.FromFile(images[counter]);
    //Image oldImage = pb1.Image;
    //pb1.Image.Dispose();
    //oldImage.Dispose();
    //pb1.Image = Image.FromFile(images[counter]);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    timer1.Stop();
    Image oldImage = pb1.Image; 
    pb1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\reflexscherm\root\sponsor1\x. Groot-logo-REFLEX.jpg");
    pb1.Image.Dispose();
    oldImage.Dispose();

    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcepath);
    string[] delfiles = Directory.GetFiles(targetpath);
    this.Hide();


    foreach (string d in delfiles)
    {
        Image oldI = pb1.Image;
        pb1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\reflexscherm\root\sponsor1\x. Groot-logo-REFLEX.jpg");
        //pb1.Image.Dispose();
        oldI.Dispose();
        File.Delete(d);
    }
    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        string fname = s.Substring(sourcepath.Length + 1);
        File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourcepath, fname), Path.Combine(targetpath, fname), true);
        this.Show();
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

What I am looking for is some help to adjust the code, so when I change files in sourcefolder then program copies the files from the sourcefolder to the targetfolder. I know how to use filewatcher.  I am using a button to test the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use a readonly File Access if you don't want it to be locked:

```
using( FileStream stream = new FileStream( path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read ) )

{

     image = Image.FromStream( stream );

}
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1: Preserve a copy and assign a Control's property**

Use this method when a Bitmap object is handled in more than one *place*, so we need to preserve it for further elaborations/assignments and save to disc after.

Assign, store and dispose of the source Bitmap immediately, deleting the Image file:

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
//---------------------------------------------

string imagePath = @"[Path of the Image]";

bitmap?.Dispose();
pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();

using (Bitmap tempImage = new Bitmap(imagePath, true))
{
    bitmap = new Bitmap(tempImage);
    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
}

File.Delete(imagePath);
```

**Method 2: Assign the Bitmap and dispose of it immediately**

This method can be used when you need to assign a Bitmap to a Control and then move/delete the Image file. The Image is disposed of immediately, so it's only available through a Control's property: if we ask to have it back, sometimes what we get is not exactly what we gave.

```
string imagePath = @"[Path of the Image]";
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(imagePath, true))
{
    pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(image);
}

File.Delete(imagePath);
```

Note that the old image assigned to the Control, if any, is disposed of before assigning a new one.

Also note I'm always specifying to preserve the internal ICM informations, if any, specifying `true` as the second parameter of both `new Bitmap(imagePath, true)` and `Image.FromFile(imagePath, true)`.
Some images won't *look* as the original if we don't.

Comment: Great ... I solved a long standing problem

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem before, i did the following:

```
            this.photo.Dispose();
            this.photo.Refresh();
            this.photo.Image.Dispose();
            this.photo.Image = null;
            this.photo.ImageLocation = null;
```

and it worths it.

Comment: thank you for the response, but it is not working for me :(

Comment: you did it in the same sequence?